# Angular component to apply parent specified styles

Tags: html, css, angular, web-component

I know how to use `::ng-deep` to apply styles to specific component's internal parts, but I'm looking for a more correct solution that does not require the parent to know about the components parts, and specifically to set dimensions of the component (width and hight).

Here's the full scenario:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<h1>Hello World!<h1><app-green-box></app-green-box>',
  styles: [ 'app-green-box { width: 50%; }' ],
})
export class AppComponent {
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-green-box',
  template: '<div class="green-box">Bye</div>',
  styles: [ '.green-box { border: solid black 1px; background: green; }' ],
})
export class GreenBoxComponent {
}
```

As you can see, `AppComponent` would like a green box that is 50% wide. `GreenBoxComponent` does not have a way to know that (another parent might want it at 70% or at 10%).

Unfortunately, the above code doesn't work (I'm not exactly sure why - the custom element doesn't actually take up space as it has no visual presentation by itself, and so it can't be a bounding box for the content?).

Using `::ng-deep` requires the parent component to know that `GreenBoxComponent` uses a `<div>` for its internal box implementation, but is there a way to have the component just "copy" the styles from the host to whatever internal part it needs to apply these to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, after trying to explain to myself the reason that the custom element isn't a bounding box (in the question), I figured out the problem: the default `display` for the custome element is `inline` so it doesn't obey the size restrictions of the parent.

The solution is for `GreenBoxComponent` to understand that it represents a box and not an inline element and that parents would like to treat it as a box - so it should force its host element to have `display: block`, like so:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-green-box',
  template: '<div class="green-box">Bye</div>',
  styles: [ 
    ':host { display: block; }',
    '.green-box { border: solid black 1px; background: green; }',
  ],
})
export class GreenBoxComponent {
}
```

Comment: The power of rubber duck debugging - nice .